# forbidden при длинном post запросе

Tags: php, html, apache, post

Кнопка:

```
<button onclick="$('#fk').submit();">
    <i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Форма:

```
<form action="/panel/shop_edit&mode=fk" method="POST" id="fk">
    <input name="fk_form" type="text">
</form>
```

PHP код:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Выхлоп:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /panel/shop_edit&mode=fk on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в пути `/panel/shop_edit&mode=fk`

Comment: Если на /test.php, то тоже не хочет

Comment: Ну тогда возможно проблема з доступом. Попробуй поставить 755

Comment: Тоже не работает. Я решил отказаться от идеи с fk т.к. там непонятная документация и ik просто лучше :D